# Delete margins in webView

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem with webView. As you can see on the picture there are white margins. I want to fill my screen that picture. How I can do that?
This is picture:
[image]

this is code:

```
    WebView web = new WebView(getContext());
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String imagePath = id;
String html = "<html><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
web.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///mnt/sdcard/DinEgen/", html, "text/html","utf-8",null);
web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

web.setInitialScale(1);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
web.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="100">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/presentation_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="95"

        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/presentation_indicatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/choose_small_normal"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u post ur xml file??

Comment: rather than adding webview dynamically into linear layout.take relative layout, add webview and viewPager in it.alignParentBottom true to viewPager.by which you can see how layout looks and wont get space between the two

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace your  tag with this one:

```
<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>
```

Here's another tip for images in a webview:
add a styling that fits images in the width of the screen. Works great on all screen sizes:

```
<style type='text/css'>
       img {max-width: 100%;height:initial;} div,p,span,a {max-width: 100%;}
       </style>
```

Comment: Ok, so the problem is probably within the html. I've edited my answer. Let me know if it helps

Comment: np. Added another tip for your images: the max-width setting

Comment: @RonenYacobi hi seems u can help me . please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449446/remove-blank-sapaces-in-webveiw-not-work

Answer (score 0):

I found this one works. This removes padding&margin and also make image sizes fit the screen width.

```
val warppedHtml = "<style>body { margin:0; padding:0;} img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;}</style>${html}"
```